# send mms by code not using intent

Tags: android, mms

I copy all code form  mms  pacakge in android open source, then i using these code to send mms:

```
     public class Mms_sampleActivity extends Activity {
    String subject = "test MMS ";
    String recipient = "13534585169"; //13800138000
    SendReq sendRequest;
    EncodedStringValue[] sub;
    byte[] bytesToSend;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MMmakePdu();

    }


    void MMmakePdu()
    {
        sendRequest = new SendReq();
        sub = EncodedStringValue.extract(subject);
        if (sub != null & sub.length != 0) {
            sendRequest.setSubject(sub[0]);
        }

        EncodedStringValue[] phoneNumbers = EncodedStringValue.extract(recipient);
        if (phoneNumbers != null & phoneNumbers.length != 0)
        {
            sendRequest.addTo(phoneNumbers[0]);
        }

        PduBody pduBody = new PduBody();
        PduPart part = new PduPart();

        part.setName("sample".getBytes());
        part.setContentType("image/png".getBytes());
        String furl = "file://mnt/sdcard//1.png";

        PduPart partPdu = new PduPart();
        partPdu.setCharset(CharacterSets.UTF_8);
        partPdu.setName(part.getName());
        partPdu.setContentType(part.getContentType());
        partPdu.setDataUri(Uri.parse(furl));
        pduBody.addPart(partPdu);

        sendRequest.setBody(pduBody);

        PduComposer composer = new PduComposer(this, sendRequest);
        bytesToSend = composer.make();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    SendMMS.sendMMMS(Mms_sampleActivity.this, bytesToSend);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }
}


       public class SendMMS {

    public static String mmscUrl = "http://mmsc.monternet.com"; 
    //public static String mmscUrl = "http://mmsc.myuni.com.cn"; 
    //public static String mmscUrl = "http://www.baidu.com";
    public static String mmsProxy = "10.0.0.172";
    public static String mmsPort = "80";

    private static String HDR_VALUE_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = "";

    private static final String HDR__KEY_ACCEPT = "Accept";
    private static final String HDR_KEY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = "Accept-Language";

    private static final String HDR_VALUE_ACCEPT = 
        "*/*, application/vnd.wap.mms-message, application/vnd.wap.sic";

    public static byte[] sendMMMS(Context context, byte[] pdu) throws Exception
    {
        //HDR_AVLUE_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = getHttpAcceptLanguage();

        if (mmscUrl == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("URL must not be null");
        }

        HttpClient client = null;
        try{
            //client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android-Mms/2.0");
            //client = HttpConnector.buileClient(context);
             URI hostUrl = new URI(mmscUrl);
                HttpHost target = new HttpHost(
                        hostUrl.getHost(), hostUrl.getPort(),
                        HttpHost.DEFAULT_SCHEME_NAME);

            client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android-Mms/2.0");

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(mmscUrl);
            ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(pdu);
            entity.setContentType("application/vnd.wap.mms-message");
            post.setEntity(entity);
            post.addHeader(HDR__KEY_ACCEPT,HDR_VALUE_ACCEPT);
            post.addHeader(HDR_KEY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, HDR_VALUE_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);

            HttpParams params = client.getParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");

             ConnRouteParams.setDefaultProxy(
                     params, new HttpHost(mmsProxy, 80));
            //req.setParams(params);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(target,post);

            StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
            System.out.println("status : " + status.getStatusCode());
            if (status.getStatusCode() != 200)
            {
                System.out.println("!200");
                throw new IOException("HTTP error: " + status.getReasonPhrase());
            }

            HttpEntity resentity = response.getEntity();
            byte[] body = null;

            if (resentity != null)
            {
                try{
                    if (resentity.getContentLength() <= 0)
                    {
                        body  =  new byte[(int)resentity.getContentLength()];
                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(resentity.getContent());

                        try{
                            dis.readFully(body);
                        }finally{
                            try{
                                dis.close();
                            }catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }finally
                {
                    if (entity != null)
                        entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("result : "+ new String(body));
            return body;

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }

}
```

my code run without any mistake,but  give me   `status.getStatusCode()=400`,i don't know if my `partPdu` is mistake or my `httppost` is mistake,can you give me some advice?

Comment: can you attached audio file with mms?also you can see the attached file?

Comment: @pengwang Is any solution found to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Can you send me MMS Send Project or Article please?? I got me a lot :(